# Why am I getting "undefined method `flatten'" when calling on an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten, nomethoderror

**Problem**

I am building a script that takes in a column from a CSV that can contain 0 or more ID numbers.
I have created an array of the column, however, since some cells have no ID number and some have multiple,I have an array of arrays.

I want to create an array where each element is a single ID (i.e split the IDs from each element in the array to a single element).

Here is my code so far:

```
require 'csv'
class MetadataTherapyParser

    def initialize (csv)
        @csv = csv
    end

    def parse_csv
        therapy_array = []
        CSV.foreach(@csv) do |csv_row|
            therapy_array << csv_row[0] 
        end
    end

    def parse_therapies(therapy_array) 
        parsed_therapy_array = therapy_array.flatten!
        puts parsed_therapy_array   
    end
end

metadata_parse = MetadataTherapyParser.new ("my_csv_path")
metadata_parse.parse_csv
metadata_parse.parse_therapies(metadata_parse)
```

**Actual Results**

I am getting the following error:

```
in `parse_therapies': undefined method `flatten' for #<MetadataTherapyParser:0x00007fd31a0b75a8> (NoMethodError)
```

From what I can find online, `flatten` is the method to use. However I can't seem to figure out why I am getting an undefined method error. I have checked to ensure that `therapy_array` is indeed an array.

If anyone has encountered this issue before and could offer some advice, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the error message, you  can clearly see that `parse_therapies` is not an Array, but a `MetadataTherapyParser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling the method `parse_therapies` instead of passing an array you are passing the `metedata_parse`, which is an object of `MetadataTherapyParser`

Try this:

```
def parse_csv
    therapy_array = []
    CSV.foreach(@csv) do |csv_row|
        therapy_array << csv_row[0] 
    end
    therapy_array
end
```

Then while calling the methods:

```
metadata_parse = MetadataTherapyParser.new ("my_csv_path")
therapy_array = metadata_parse.parse_csv
metadata_parse.parse_therapies(therapy_array)
```

This should pass an Array instead of `MetadataTherapyParser` object to your parse method.

Comment: @belle Do let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @ Ekamjit Singh I just printed the results and it seems to still be a nested array